# How to rotate specific tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

Use case: you have tick marks on the x axis. But some ticks are either too close or you need to otherwise emphasize them via rotation. So, for example, you might have a list of dates across the x axis that are always first of the month. But then you want to 'call out' one date in particular, say your birthday, and rotate it, say, 25 degrees.

*How could you rotate that one 'tick' while NOT rotating all the others?*

I know `plt.xticks(rotation = 335)` will rotate all the ticks nicely.

But let's say you have:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))

ax.set_xticks((0,1455,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000))
```

and you want to rotate `1455` by 335 degrees, while **NOT** rotating any of the others.

***How do you do it?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you set the tick positions (and optionally also set their labels), you can access the matplotlib text elements via `ax.get_xticklabels()`.
So, you can just access the second element in the list and change its rotation.  (Similarly, you can e.g. change colors.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
ax.set_xticks((0, 1455, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000))
ticks = ax.get_xticklabels()
ticks[1].set_rotation(335)
plt.show()
```

[image: rotating one tick label]

This applies to `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, `matplotlib`, and `seaborn`.